# Embed Opengl into Windows Forms application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opengl

I need to draw a rectangle when button is clicked on the form, so that a triangle should be drawn inside a rectangle.

- I have created a windows forms application with VS 2010 Ultimate with VC++.
- And I have embedded OpenGL rendering window inside that windows form.

I went through [Creating OpenGL window on Windows Form Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16051/Creating-an-OpenGL-view-on-a-Windows-Form#xx4457919xx) to get the following output:

[image: Rectangle drawn with OpenGL]

And it really worked well for me.

I don't understand how and where to write the code for rectangle creation when the button clicks.

Comment: It looks like that code project article refers to a method named Render. Have you tried putting your code to draw a rectangle in there?

Comment: Dear Trana, You mean to use my void method for draw rectangle inside render method?But what will happen to the differences that I have to make in the main method?

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Generally speaking, render gets called all the time. When you click the button, you need to change something so that the render loop realizes it needs to draw a rectangle and also knows how to. I think to get more traction on this question you're going to want to post the relevant parts of the code you have.